# Is the order of observables given to combineLatest relevant?

Tags: rxjs, reactive

I have two observables which I want to combine with `combineLatest`:

```
const o1 = from(['a', 'b', 'c']);
const o2 = of('content from o2');
combineLatest(o1, o2)
  .subscribe(result => console.log(result));
```

As I understood `combineLatest`, when **any** observable emits, it will combine the latest values of all observables and emit them:

> When any observable emits a value, emit the latest value from each.
>   (https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html)

However, with the code above, the output is:

```
["c", "content from o2"]
```

So only when `o2` emits, `combineLatest` emits an value.

If I switch the order I hand over `o1` and `o2`, it works as expected:

```
const o1 = from(['a', 'b', 'c']);
const o2 = of('content from o2');
combineLatest(o2, o1)
  .subscribe(result => console.log(result));
```

Output:

```
["content from o2", "a"]
["content from o2", "b"]
["content from o2", "c"]
```

Is this expected behavior? If so, why? This seems to contradict the definition ob `combineLatest`.

Comment: https://staltz.com/primer-on-rxjs-schedulers.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, in this case order matters, but it is a timing issue. combineLatest can not influence the order in which the values of the observables are emitted.

In your first case, o1 emits all values before o2 emits its value. In your second case o2 emits its value first and then o1 emits all its values. In real world examples you have a natural delay of observable values (service calls etc..) and so normally order does not matter.

Answer (score -1):

I cannot stress how useful I've found `combineLatestObject` from [rxjs-etc](https://github.com/cartant/rxjs-etc/blob/master/source/observable/combineLatestObject.ts) by @cartant.

You provide an object with named observables and then instead of getting an array back you get an object with the named values.

```
combineLatestObject({

   isRaining: this.isRaining$,
   isSnowing: this.isSnowing$

}).pipe(map(({ isSnowing, isRaining }) => {

   return (isSnowing ? "It's snowing " : "It isn't snowing ") + "and " +
          (isRaining ? "it's raining " : "it isn't raining");

});
```

Inside `map()` or `switchMap()` you can deconstruct the object like I did here, or just provide a single parameter where you can access the values `map(data => data.isSnowing)`.

It's so much safer and easier to read - and when I look back at old code I did I find it so hard to read. Note in the example above I've deliberately put the parameters in a different order and no issues doing so.

Why this isn't part of the main library I don't know!

Comment: Nice, but you can actually deconstruct it this way too: ```combineLatest(this.isRaining$, this.isSnowing$).pipe(map([isRaining, isSnowing]) => {...});```